# Do I need to pre-stain sanded stairs?

Tags: finishing

I'm redoing my stairs and I sanded them, I don't know what kind of wood they are, do I need to put a pre-stain on them?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to answer this question directly — what's sold as "pre-stain conditioner" is for controlling blotching in blotch-prone woods and without knowing the species we can't advise on whether it's required or not.

You might be able to find out empirically by testing the stain you have on the wood in a less-visible spot, or the underside of one of the treads if you can get access to them. If you get blotching then you know you need to pre-treat the wood.

Note: if you'll be using "gel stain" this isn't actually stain in the conventional meaning of the word, and one of its main advantages is that it sidesteps the need for pre-treating the wood. So, if you're using gel stain you don't need pre-stain.